# Clear field with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form, that when submitted, needs to have the input field cleared.

I'm using useState and inside my `addNewColor` method, I'm resetting the `newName` state to go back to an empty string. The initial state is an empty string, so I figured I would just call `setName(newName)` as that's my initial state, but it didn't work. I know there is some way to use `prevState`, but I haven't gotten my head around it yet. I apologize for the confusing summary.

In short, I'm just trying to clear the field. I'm using Material UI and the name sits within the TextValidator component.

```
const NewPaletteForm = () => {
  const [currentColor, setColor] = useState("teal");
  const [colors, setColors] = useState([]);
  const [newName, setName] = useState("");

  function addNewColor() {
    const newColor = {
      color: currentColor,
      name: newName
    };

    const resetName = {
      name: ""
    };

    setName(newName, resetName);
    setColors([...colors, newColor]);
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }
};

<ValidatorForm onSubmit={addNewColor}>
  <TextValidator
    value={newName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    validators={["required", "isColorNameUnique", "isColorUnique"]}
    errorMessages={[
      "Enter a color name",
      "Color name must be unique",
      "Color is already used"
    ]}
  />
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    type="submit"
    color="primary"
    style={{ backgroundColor: currentColor }}
  >
    Add Color
  </Button>
</ValidatorForm>;
```

Comment: `setName("")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the useState hook.

The returned array from useState looks like: `['currentValue', 'methodToSetValue']`

So to reset the name, you can simply call `setName("")`, which will set the current value to "".

If you need the previous value (not to clear but to update from it for example), you can pass a function into setName:

```
setName(prevName => prevName+' Surname');
```

This would append `Surname` to the current name.

Comment: Thank you. It was a major misunderstanding on my point and I should have did more research before asking. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setName('')` to reset the name. Also if for some reason you need to get access to the current state, use the functional form of `setState`:

```
setName(name => {
  // Do smth with the name
  return name; // Return updated state
);
```